# Creating a timer with CreateTimerQueueTimer, Visual Studio 2012 ,C++ , running periodically

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, timer, period

I am trying to use `CreateTimerQueueTimer(...)` to run a function every so often.

I am using an example from MSDN and mainly this line concerns me :

```
CreateTimerQueueTimer( &hTimer, hTimerQueue,(WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)TimerRoutine, &arg , 50,100, 0)
```

which the syntax is :

```
BOOL WINAPI CreateTimerQueueTimer(
  _Out_     PHANDLE phNewTimer,
  _In_opt_  HANDLE TimerQueue,
  _In_      WAITORTIMERCALLBACK Callback,
  _In_opt_  PVOID Parameter,
  _In_      DWORD DueTime,
  _In_      DWORD Period,
  _In_      ULONG Flags
);
```

The second to last argument states

> Period [in]
>
> The period of the timer, in milliseconds. If this parameter is zero, the timer is signaled once. If this parameter is greater than zero, the timer is periodic. A periodic timer automatically reactivates each time the period elapses, until the timer is canceled.

As you can see in my code, I set the Due time for 50 and the period as 100. When I run it, it does not `repeat` firing the timer. Can someone help me with this ?

Here is the entire code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

HANDLE gDoneEvent;

VOID CALLBACK TimerRoutine(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    if (lpParam == NULL)
    {
        printf("TimerRoutine lpParam is NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // lpParam points to the argument; in this case it is an int

        printf("Timer routine called. Parameter is %d.\n", 
                *(int*)lpParam);
        if(TimerOrWaitFired)
        {
            printf("The wait timed out.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The wait event was signaled.\n");
        }
    }

    SetEvent(gDoneEvent);
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    HANDLE hTimerQueue = NULL;
    int arg = 123,x;


    // Use an event object to track the TimerRoutine execution
    gDoneEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (NULL == gDoneEvent)
    {
        printf("CreateEvent failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Create the timer queue.
    hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();
    if (NULL == hTimerQueue)
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }

    // Set a timer to call the timer routine in 10 seconds.
    if (!CreateTimerQueueTimer( &hTimer, hTimerQueue,(WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)TimerRoutine, &arg , 50,100, 0))
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueueTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 3;
    }

    // TODO: Do other useful work here 

    printf("Call timer routine in 10 seconds...\n");

    // Wait for the timer-queue thread to complete using an event 
    // object. The thread will signal the event at that time.

    if (WaitForSingleObject(gDoneEvent, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

    CloseHandle(gDoneEvent);

    // Delete all timers in the timer queue.
    if (!DeleteTimerQueue(hTimerQueue))
        printf("DeleteTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
    cin>>x;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Your code works for me. What exactly is the output your expect?

Comment: 'Call timer routine in 10 seconds...
timer routine called. Parameter is 123.
The wait timed out'

then it waits for my keyboard command.

Answer (score 1):

Event `gDoneEvent` is signaled before the function `TimerRoutine()` exits. For repeated calls to the callback function, signal the event `gDoneEvent` after the function `TimerRoutine()` is called required number of times.

Could include the following lines of codes.

```
static int count = 0;

VOID CALLBACK TimerRoutine(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    ......
    count++;
    if(count == 100)
    {
         SetEvent(gDoneEvent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lokesh is right, although as a c++ beginner I didn't get their answer at first.

You need to make sure `SetEvent(gDoneEvent);` is called only when you want the timer to stop. For my needs I just commented it out as I wanted the timer to run continuously.